# Problems spring-cloud-config and spring-cloud-bus

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-bus

I have three applications ,one is spring-cloud-config server point and others are spring-cloud-config client points. I configured spring-cloud-bus in each other to make my client points auto refresh changed but in my application running ,I got a Exception like

```
    c.netflix.discovery.TimedSupervisorTask  : task supervisor rejected the task

java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@17834c50 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1944b0d0[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at com.netflix.discovery.TimedSupervisorTask.run(TimedSupervisorTask.java:62) ~[eureka-client-1.4.6.jar:1.4.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]
```

this is my spring-cloud-server config

```
#git config
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri = ###
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=###
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=###
spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths = puhui-cloud-config-client

#spring.active.profile
spring.profiles.active=dev

#spring-cloud-bus-amqp config
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=/
```

this is my spring-cloud-config server pom

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

this is my spring-cloud-config client config

```
#spring-cloud-config
spring.cloud.config.discovery.serviceId = PUHUI-CLOUD-CONFIG-SERVER
spring.cloud.config.name = @project.artifactId@
spring.cloud.config.profile = @profiles.active@
spring.cloud.config.label= master

spring.rabbitmq.host = localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port = 5672
```

this is my spring-cloud-config client point pom

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This exception will not affect the application of the operation, but I want to know why the application throws the exception

Comment: Seems to be related with [spring-cloud-netflix#1055](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1055).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to enable register and fetch registry for client in discovery server

```
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true

eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
```

Comment: I tried these configurations, and they did not get rid of that exception.

Answer (score 2):

This was an issue with Eureka itself, try to upgrade eureka version which you're using. You can check this https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2228

Answer (score 0):

I think the error logs are related to Eureka. Are you running Eureka server? You have added Eureka dependencies in your pom file, but I don't see any Eureka related configuration in your properties file. Try without those dependencies or build a Eureka server and run with them. Or at least, add the following property  in your configuration file.

```
eureka.client.enabled=false
```

Comment: oh, Really I had  a eureka server, and  eureka configuration is eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=@eureka.defaultZone@
eureka.instance.hostname=${spring.cloud.client.ipAddress}
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **application.yml** file for project config, you can enable register and fetch registry for client in discovery server:

```
eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
```